# How do you add more players in WWE Raw Total Edition?

Tags: mods, technical-issues

I have downloaded a mod for WWE Raw Total Edition. It has lots of images of WWE's superstars and arenas, but I don't know how to use them. How can I add them to the game? Is there any tool by which we can use them?

Answer (score 4):

Import the files using [XPKGUI](http://www.angelfire.com/electronic2/tgk/xpkgui030.htm) (which I recommend) or XPKPORT. You should be able to find the latter through Google.